# Sorting in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I would like to sort data in MS Access, and for that I am using a query. The data in my table is like:

```
  RadButtonNo
-------------------
    AA001056    
    AA001579    
    B000049
    AA001261
    AA001158
    AA001108
    AA001166
    AA001165
    AA001164
    AA001163
    AA001162
```

For my output, the data I would like first would be only data which consists of letters.  Following that, I would like to display letters and numbers.  So, it would look something like this:

```
    AAAAAAA
    AABBBBB
    AAZZZZZ
    ABA1001
```

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT RadButtonNo, ShortName, InspectionDate, Findings, Status, QueryForNot1.Initials, DeptName, Lost, TableApron.InServelDate, TableApron.RemovedDate,
     TableApron.PrivateUserName, TableApron.PrivateUserEmail, TableApron.ApronType, TableApron.Manufacturer
    FROM TableApron 
    LEFT JOIN QueryForNot1 ON TableApron.RadButtonNo=QueryForNot1.RadButtonNoI
    WHERE (((TableApron.Lost)="N" Or (TableApron.Lost)=[@Lost]) 
    ORDER BY LEN(TableApron.RadButtonNo) DESC , TableApron.RadButtonNo;
```

Can someone fix this so that it will produce my desired output?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please re-read and edit your question, it is hardly understandable.

Comment: @Andre451 i have edited the question can you understand it

Comment: A normal sort of the field will sort as your example, so what is your problem, please?

Comment: @Gustav i want that first short from string A to Z then It start from A(number Like 1,2 etc) Example - `AAAA` ,`AAAB` like this after finishing this A With numbers Example - 'AAA1`,`AAA2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two functions:

```
Public Function TrimNumString( _
  ByVal strNumString As String, _
  Optional ByVal strDecimalChr As String, _
  Optional ByVal booAcceptMinus As Boolean) _
  As String

' Removes any non-numeric character from strNumString including hexadecimal characters.
' If strDecimalChr is specified, first occurrence of this is not removed.
' If booAcceptMinus is True, a leading or trailing minus sign is accepted.
'
' 1999-08-27. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' 2001-06-21. Speed optimized for large string (64 K).
' 2003-12-10. intOffset changed to lngOffset.

  Const cbytNeg   As Byte = 45  ' "-"

  Dim lngPos      As Long
  Dim lngLen      As Long
  Dim lngOffset   As Long
  Dim booDec      As Boolean
  Dim booNeg      As Boolean
  Dim bytChr      As Byte
  Dim bytDec      As Byte
  Dim strNum      As String

  strNumString = Trim(strNumString)
  lngLen = Len(strNumString)
  If lngLen > 0 Then
    If Len(strDecimalChr) > 0 Then
      bytDec = Asc(strDecimalChr)
    End If
    ' Create empty result string of maximum possible length.
    strNum = Space(lngLen)

    For lngPos = 1 To lngLen
      bytChr = Asc(Mid(strNumString, lngPos, 1))
      Select Case bytChr
        Case 48 To 57
          ' Digit.
        Case bytDec
          ' Decimal point.
          If booDec = False Then
            ' One decimal point only.
            booDec = True
          End If
        Case cbytNeg
          ' Minus sign.
          bytChr = 0
          If booAcceptMinus = True And booNeg = False Then
            If Len(Trim(strNum)) = 0 Or lngPos = lngLen Then
              bytChr = cbytNeg
              ' One minus sign only.
              booNeg = True
            End If
          End If
        Case Else
          ' Ignore any other character.
          bytChr = 0
      End Select
      If bytChr > 0 Then
        ' Append accepted character by inserting it in result string.
        lngOffset = lngOffset + 1
        Mid(strNum, lngOffset) = Chr(bytChr)
      End If
    Next
  End If

  ' Trim and return result string.
  TrimNumString = Left(strNum, lngOffset)

End Function


Public Function TrimTxtString( _
  ByVal strTxtString As String) _
  As String

' Removes any numeric character from strTxtString.
'
' 2003-12-19. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim lngPos      As Long
  Dim lngLen      As Long
  Dim lngOffset   As Long
  Dim bytChr      As Byte
  Dim strNum      As String

  strTxtString = Trim(strTxtString)
  lngLen = Len(strTxtString)
  If lngLen > 0 Then
    ' Create empty result string of maximum possible length.
    strNum = Space(lngLen)

    For lngPos = 1 To lngLen
      bytChr = Asc(Mid(strTxtString, lngPos, 1))
      Select Case bytChr
        Case 48 To 57
          ' Digit.
          bytChr = 0
        Case Else
          ' Accept any other character.
      End Select
      If bytChr > 0 Then
        ' Append accepted character by inserting it in result string.
        lngOffset = lngOffset + 1
        Mid(strNum, lngOffset) = Chr(bytChr)
      End If
    Next
  End If

  ' Trim and return result string.
  TrimTxtString = Left(strNum, lngOffset)

End Function
```

Then adjust your SQL:

```
ORDER BY LEN(TableApron.RadButtonNo) DESC, TrimTxtString([TableApron].[RadButtonNo]), TrimNumString([TableApron].[RadButtonNo]);
```

Comment: i want this can be done in sql script in ms access , Can we do

Comment: so i add  ms access tag only

Answer (score 0):

Group entries by appending a character/or more to the entries with digits. Sort o that new field. I use here a value with all z and extra z to exclude a real entry of z's.

```
SELECT RadButtonNo
from tbl
order by IIF(RadButtonNo like "*#*", "zzzzzzzzz" & RadButtonNo, RadButtonNo)
```